# Is it posssible to flush trailer header to the client?

Tags: go, http2

This results in 2 DATA frames being sent from a server:

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write("foo")
    w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
    w.Write("bar")
    w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
}
```

This results in 1 HEADERS frames being sent from a server:

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Trailer:X", "a")
    w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
    w.Header().Set("Trailer:Y", "b")
    w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
}
```

**Is there any way to get trailer frames sent as multiple HEADERS frames without using the framer api?**

Answer (score 0):

#### If you just need to make sure trailers are flushed into the underlying socket:

Use [ConnState](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) hook to signal about trailers being written to connection. [This](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=78188:82485#L1937) is the point when the trailers are written and connection changes its state to StateIdle.

#### If you want to make sure that trailers are sent in separate frames:

[Hijack](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Hijacker) TCP connection, write the terminating chunk and trailers into the connection manually, flush the connection, close the connection. This is (obviously) not compatible with keepalive.